# How to use foreach loops to retrieve info in a nested array composed of two+ arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

What I'm trying to do is take the 2 (currently, but will end up being 4 total) arrays with the same type of results, put them all together, sort them by one of their values(post_time), and echo them to the screen in that sorted order.

I can echo out these results by their individual results/arrays with a while loop, but they won't be sorted correctly by the post time in total, only within their individual arrays.

I'm getting confused between nested foreach loops. I've tried array_merge on the two arrays I have, then putting that array into another array just to have a numeric key to loop through, but I'm stuck, confused and tired. I've done research but I just can't wrap my head around comparing the answers I'm seeing with my own particular code.

I need some help. Here's what I've got. This is the code retrieving the separate sets/arrays of information from the database.

```
include 'db_connect.php';
include 'core.php';

$get_char = mysql_query("SELECT character_id FROM characters WHERE account_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
$char = mysql_result($get_char,0,'character_id');

$get_location = mysql_query("SELECT current_location, x_cord, y_cord, inside_building FROM characters WHERE character_id = $char");
$location = mysql_result($get_location, 0, 'current_location');
$x = mysql_result($get_location,0, 'x_cord');
$y = mysql_result($get_location,0,'y_cord');
$inside = mysql_result($get_location,0,'inside_building');

//get all messages where current characters arrival time is less than post_time
//AND arrival location is the same as posting location
$get_arrival = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM arrive_exit WHERE character_id = $char ORDER BY arrival DESC");
while($arrivals = mysql_fetch_array($get_arrival)){
  $arrival = $arrivals['arrival'];
  $arrival_location = $arrivals['location'];
  $unix_arrival = strtotime($arrival);
  $exit = $arrivals['exit'];
  $unix_exit = strtotime($exit);
  if(!isset($exit)){
    $get_logs = mysql_query("SELECT character_id, log, post_time, event FROM character_logs WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post_time) >= $unix_arrival
    AND location = $arrival_location ORDER BY post_time DESC");
  }else{
    $get_logs = mysql_query("SELECT character_id, log, post_time, event FROM character_logs WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post_time) >= $unix_arrival
    AND location = $arrival_location AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post_time) <= $unix_exit ORDER BY post_time DESC");
  }
  $o_logs = mysql_fetch_array($get_logs);

  //CHECK FOR LOGS IN BUILDING LOGS
  if(!isset($exit)){
    $check_logs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM building_logs WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post_time) >= $unix_arrival
    AND current_location = $arrival_location");
  }else{
    $check_logs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM building_logs WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post_time) >= $unix_arrival
    AND current_location = $arrival_location");
  }
  $building_check = mysql_num_rows($check_logs);
  if($building_check >= 1){
    $get_room = mysql_query("SELECT room_id, building_current_id, building_id FROM building_logs WHERE character_id = $char");
    $room_id = mysql_result($get_room,0,'room_id');
    $building_current = mysql_result($get_room,0,'building_current_id');
    $building_id = mysql_result($get_room,0,'building_id');
    if(!isset($exit)){
      $get_logs = mysql_query("SELECT character_id, log, post_time, event FROM building_logs WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post_time) >= $unix_arrival
      AND current_location = $arrival_location AND x = $x AND y = $y AND room_id = $room_id ORDER BY post_time DESC");
    }else{
    $get_logs = mysql_query("SELECT character_id, log, post_time, event FROM building_logs WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post_time) >= $unix_arrival
    AND current_location = $arrival_location AND x = $x AND y = $y AND room_id = $room_id
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(post_time) <= $unix_exit ORDER BY post_time DESC");
    }
    $b_logs = mysql_fetch_array($get_logs);
  }
}
```

Here's the non-working code I've tried to use to manipulate the retrieved results.

```
$list = array_merge((array)$o_logs,(array)$b_logs);
$messages = array($list);
//echo out info here.
foreach($messages as $array){
  foreach($array as $log_key => $value){
    //log_key in this case could be character_id, event, post_time, so on which is not preferable
    echo $log_key.' : '.$value.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
0 : 62
character_id : 64
1 : This is a testing log from a different person at an earlier time in a DIFFERENT location.
log : This is a log from inside a building now.
2 : 2013-02-22 04:04:00
post_time : 2013-02-26 19:00:00
3 : 0
event : 0
4 : 64
5 : This is a log from inside a building now.
6 : 2013-02-26 19:00:00
7 : 0
```

So, obviously I'm getting keys which are also strings from the inner foreach loop. They're coming from the second "building_logs" query. I wasn't expecting my output from the quickly jotted loop nest above to give me exactly what I wanted, but I will say I don't know why that's happening.

I need help understanding how to nest the foreach loops to properly get the information I need, please. I would appreciate it very much, as even though I've been coding for over a year, I've barely had to deal with any loops other than while loops and the arrays I worked with were never multidimensional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)` contains every value from the DB **twice**,
(1) as a numerical array and
(2) as an associative array:

(1) `$row[0]="Hello"` and
(2) `$row['text']="Hello"`

try `... mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM)` to get numerical indices only, or
`.. MYSQL_ASSOC)`to get associative indices only.

`array_merge`...
"If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended."
quoting from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

I guess this is explaining the strange results you are getting.

So, first set `mysql_get_array($result,MYSQL_NUM)`, then merge the arrays into `$list`, then sort them (see php.net), then echo them.

`$messages = array($list);` doesn't make much sense to me, though.

do `var_dump($list);` to get an idea of how this array is built. Then adjust the loop accordingly.

BTW, I forgot to mention that mysql_* is deprecated, move to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has helped immensely. And yes, sorry, I should have noted that I have yet to move to mysqli because I started this project before I knew that mysql was to be deprecated. I'll be changing it in one swoop later on. THANK YOU, again, for your help.